# Lua on redis error: Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'require'

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, redis

This is the test script I am trying to execute:

```
local cjson = require "cjson"
local json_text = '[ true, { "foo": "bar" } ]'
local value = cjson.decode(json_text)
return 'Decoded: ' .. value
```

Its giving a strange response:

```
evalsha 76b573109be38414056b58c749016a56052063bd 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_76b573109be38414056b58c749016a56052063bd): @enable_strict_lua:15: user_script:1: Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'require'
```

How come the compiler isn't able to understand the keyword "require"? I am using redis 3.0.5 (running Lua 5.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`require` is not available within Redis, libraries are preloaded. Just remove the first line of your script and it should work.

Comment: Redis could just have simplified the loaders list to leave the preload loader only. Or simply redefine `require`
.